# Reset password with HyN Multitenant in Laravel does not work

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I work with HyN Multitenant, the issue is that I need to recover the password of a user to send the mail occupying the drivers that come by default with AUTH.

The topic goes that when recovering the password it does not work, it throws me an error that it does not find the table in the DB, is but, it does not recognize the tenant of the connection, try to add him/her the trait but there is not solution.

In Config/Auth.php I configure the connection and nothing takes me the DB connection but not the tenant.

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
        'connection' => 'system',
    ],
],
```

[image]

Comment: have you really try to inspect your DB and .env file?

also, show the query and the Model class code to make us help you

Comment: Yes, because I have the whole system working, with the Multi Tenant, and it's the only thing that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You only need set:

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
        'connection' => 'tenant',
    ],
]
```

And in the `ForgotPasswordController` set `use SendsPasswordResetEmails, UsesTenantConnection;`